# Tkinter - automatic assign rows and columns in grid

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I've tried the search functionality (and a google) but can't seem to find a good/pythonic way of doing this.

I'm trying to dynamically fill a tkinter Frame (although it could be any widget) using a *for* loop - I'd like to fill three columns and then go to the next row in the grid. My code is as below:

```
    cols = 0
    rows = 0
    for item in comparison['dif_changed']:
            Label(master=first_chord, text=item[-22:]+",", bg='white').grid(column=cols, row=rows, sticky=W)
            cols+=1
            if cols == 3:
                cols=0
                rows+=1
```

It works fine, but it's messy and I'd like to know if there is a more robust way of doing this. I come across it a lot, and feel that I'm probably missing something blindingly obvious.

Comment: What do you mean by messy? This should apply 3 items per row.

Comment: It does and works fine, but I was looking for a cleaner way of doing this - I've got about 10 different parts of the GUI with similar code (slightly different numbers of cols and rows) and didn't know if there would be a better, cleaner solution.

Comment: Well I would say what you are doing is the preferred method for dynamically assigning rows and columns. I personally don't think this way is messy and is much better than what some people do. IE Write out each widget manually. Maybe if you want a general class that can do all this for all of your code you can write a class that can take a few arguments (Container name, total columns, list or dict of widgets) and with a class like this you can use it to apply all your columns and rows by passing `custome_gridding_class(frame, 3, list)`.